# Dialog is not visible when i use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, accessibility, android-overlay

I am showing a dialog box on top of other applications. it is working till i use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`

As i am changing my target version to 26, i should not use TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, So i used `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`

after that my dialog is not visible. What else i have to do? Any suggestion.

**Reference link:** https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#cwt

Code:

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());

    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.permission);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Can you also post your layout, please? Also, where do you invoke this code?

Answer (score 3):

For oreo and above devices we have to use the TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, for below we have to use TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

```
          final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
          if(oreoAndAbove) {
              dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
          } else {
              dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
          }
          dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          dialog.setContentView(R.layout.permission);
          dialog.setCancelable(true);

          dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may miss request permission for your app.Before show window check it. If app has no permission then request it.

1.check permission by:

```
public boolean checkPermission(Context context){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return Settings.canDrawOverlays(context);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

2.do request permission by:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + context.packageName)))
```